# What is a "control cohort"?

Tags: terminology

What is the difference between "mailed cohorts" and "control cohorts"?

I've been given a dataset to analyse but I'm not sure on what columns 2 and 3 refer to. I'm unfamiliar with the terminology used. The data relates to a traditional campaign carried out by a marketing company.

- col1: Score Rank
- col2: Control Cohort Response Rate
- col3: Mailed Cohort Response Rate
- col4: Incremental Response Rate

```
1 27.9% 27.0% -0.90%
2 20.9% 20.3% -0.60%
3 10.0% 10.7%  0.70%
4  7.5%  8.9%  1.40%
```

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to say from what we have, but I'd guess that they are testing a new strategy `Mailed` against a [control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_control) (otherwise similar condition, but without the mailed aspect).  I'm guessing that "[cohort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohort_%28statistics%29)" in this context just means group of people.  That is, there is one group of people who were mailed something, and another group of people who weren't.

You should get more information from whoever is doing this study.  You cannot be expected to properly analyze data if you don't know what the numbers refer to.

It doesn't look like the mailing has made much difference.